# Foreground a bash command with & at the end

Tags: linux, bash, jobs

How could one foreground a bash command in Linux terminal such as

```
sleep 100 &
```

Comment: The bash manual covers all of this under [job control](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Builtins.html).

Comment: Had no idea where to look for, thanks

Comment: But why would like to run the `sleep` in background? Doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I have a vim macro for building my project and I added & in the end of that. However since it prints to the stdout it didn't handle it properly. I didn't know how to cancel the command and had to wait for the build to complete. No biggie, but would have been easier if I knew how to kill it.

Comment: @JoonatanSamuel : Makes sense. Another valuable resource on this topic can be found  [\[ **here** \]](https://kb.iu.edu/d/afnw). It mentions about stopped processes as well as continuing stopped process in background. Also, mind that in `jobs` result, a `+` is attached to the **JOBSPEC** of the current job. If you just use `fg` without a **JOBSPEC** the current job will be taken to the foreground.

Comment: @sjsam: He's giving a minimal, complete, and verifiable example. We don't need to know which command he's *actually* using, `sleep` is ubiquitous and fully sufficient to prove the point. ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`jobs` will show you all the running jobs. You can then use the `fg %<job number>` command to bring a specific job to the foreground. E.g.:

```
$ sleep 100 &
[1] 19480
$ jobs
[1]+  Running                 sleep 100 &
$ fg %1
```